# puppet duplicate resources and virtual resources

Tags: puppet

**Overview**

I just started using Puppet and have been unable to suss something.

**Problem**

Because of normalization, when I add two classes to a node with packages that have the same dependencies it fails.

In simple terms have duplicate resources - in this case the package `libssl`.

Note: packages are being held to prevent latest packages being installed.

**Question**

What's the best practice way to get round this?

```
class ssh {
  package { 'openssh-server':
    ensure  => installed,
    require => Package['libssl'],
  }
  package { 'libssl': ensure => installed, }
}

class apache {
  package { 'apache':
    ensure   => installed,
    require  => Package['libssl'], 
  }        
  package { 'libssl': ensure => installed, }
}

node server {
  include apache
  include openssl-server
```

Answer (score 7):

You have two choices that are going to look almost the same.

1: make it it's own class.

```
class ssh {
  package { 'openssh-server':
    ensure => present,
    require => Class['ssl'],
  }
}
class ssl {
  package { 'libssl': ensure => present, }
}
```

2: virtual resource

```
class vpackages {
  @package { 'libssl': }
}
class ssh {
  include vpackages
  package { 'openssh-server':
    ensure => present,
    require => Package['libssl'],
  }
  realize Package['libssl']
}
```

I find it better to break dependencies out into their own modules rather than use virtual resources.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using the standard package management to manage the packages installed via Puppet than you should be able to leave off the `libssl` package dependency in Puppet as that will be handled automatically via the package management system on most systems.

On Debian/Ubuntu as well as RedHat/CentOS/SuSE systems the package management tools will look for dependencies and unless you've gone out of your way to stop the default behavior the additional dependent packages will be included when Puppet tells the system to install the package (in your case simply `openssh-server` or `apache`)

Comment: Yes this would be OK if the latest packages were being used.  In my case older packages are being 'held' and hence the package versions and dependencies have to specified in the class otherwise Ubuntu goes off and attempts to install the latest version.  In doing so I have different classes which have the same package dependencies and hence this resource/package is specified in both classes and because of normalization I get an error!  hope this clears up the question

Comment: Well Debian/Ubuntu only holds one version of a package in a distro repo. Only way you'd have multiples is if you're pointing to additional repos that duplicate packages. If you're not wanting to run the latest updates that would include security and bug fixes that's great. I always love insecure machines on the network for the script kiddies to find just like the next guy.

Comment: Yes I have some back port repos for some specific packages.  Don't worry there safe from harm ;)

Comment: If that's the case why don't you PIN the back port repo version so it has priority and then you don't have to hold back packages?

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit ugly, but there's a defined() function that returns back true/false. This way you can define resources multiple times, but only "realize" them the first time they're evaluated. (use puppet run stages!)

e.g.,

```
if defined(Package['libssl']) == false {
  package { 'libssl':
    ensure => installed, 
  }
}
```